# Use list to filter another list in python

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
data_list = ['a.1','b.2','c.3']
```

And I want to retrieve only strings that start with strings from another list:

```
test_list = ['a.','c.']
```

`a.1` and `c.3` should be returned.

I suppose I could use a double for-loop:

```
for data in data_list:
    for test in test_list:
       if data.startswith(test):
           # do something with item
```

I was wondering if there was something more elegant and perhaps more peformant.

Comment: Are the strings in test_list of arbitrary length?

Comment: @jh314 yea could be any length.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`str.startswith` can also take a *tuple* (but not a list) of prefixes:

```
test_tuple=tuple(test_list)
for data in data_list:
    if data.startswith(test_tuple):
        ...
```

which means a simple list comprehension will give you the filtered list:

```
matching_strings = [ x for x in data_list if x.startswith(test_tuple) ]
```

or a call to `filter`:

```
import operator
f = operator.methodcaller( 'startswith', tuple(test_list) )
matching_strings = filter( f, test_list )
```

Comment: That's cool! I didn't know `startswith` could take a tuple :)

Comment: Any reason to use `x for x` instead `lambda x:`, or vice versa?

Comment: Well, there's no call to use a lambda with a list comprehension. But if you're asking about using a list comprehension instead of `filter` (which could have used a lambda in place of the function returned by `methodcaller`), then no, no particular reason to use one over the other, I think. I suspect each has similar performance, and I'll let others argue over which is more Pythonic :).

Comment: I never used filters/lambdas, list comprehensions or `any`. Good stuff, i'll look into them more.

Comment: I think there's endless argument about filter and map vs list-comprehensions.  Personally, I'll use whichever seems clearer to me.  In this case, you're literally filtering the data, so I'd say `filter` is remarkably clear. :-)

Comment: Just to touch on the performance side. Using dictionaries likely allows for a linear time algorithm. Although, it's only viable if you can predict what it'll be looking for which seems like it might be so. The alternative is to sort both lists, and implement a modified version of [merge operation][1] of merge sort, and use that to ensure that you only have to traverse each list once (after sorting), which allows for a O(N log N) algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#filter) with a [lambda function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) and [`startswith`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
data_list = ['a.1','b.2','c.3']
test_list = ('a.','c.')

result = filter(lambda x: x.startswith(test_list), data_list)

print(list(result))
```

Output:

```
['a.1', 'c.3']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
for data in data_list:
    if any(data.startswith(test) for test in test_list):
        # do something
```

`any()` is a builtin that takes an iterable and returns `True` on the first value from the iterable that bool's true, else returns `False`. In my example, I'm using a generator expression, instead of building a list (which would be wasteful).

Comment: `any()` would be good if all that was required was to know if there was a match, but here we need to return the match as well; which is why I upvoted @chepner's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [any](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) in the python docs.

```
>>> data_list = ['a.1','b.2','c.3']
>>> test_list = ['a.','c.']
>>> new_list = filter(lambda x: any(x.startswith(t) for t in test_list), data_list)
>>> new_list
['a.1', 'c.3']
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the stuff in your `new_list`.

As @Chepner points out, you can also supply a tuple of strings to `startswith`, so the above could also be written:

```
>>> data_list = ['a.1','b.2','c.3']
>>> test_tuple = ('a.','c.')
>>> new_list = filter(lambda x: x.startswith(test_tuple), data_list)
>>> new_list
['a.1', 'c.3']
```

Comment: Something wrong with the first one, it did not return something.

Comment: sry, you're right. I just ran `filter(...)` in PyScripter. Usually I see output on the console but it didn't show it this time unless I added `print`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, break out regular expressions

```
import re
# build a pattern that matches any of the strings we are interested in 
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, test_list))) 
# filter by matches
print filter(pattern.match, data_list)
```

This probably moves the most possible into C and may be more efficient than the other solutions. It may be a bit tricky for the uninitiated to follow though.

Comment: If I change `test_list` to `['2','c.']` I would think this would give me `b.2` as well as `c.3`, but it only gives me `c.3`. The regex produced is `2|c\.`, so I don't know why it didn't return `b.2`.

Comment: @AndyArismendi, match only matches at the beginning of strings.